# Prometheus: Missing data point of metrics which aggregated by recording rule

Tags: prometheus

Environment Info:
[image]

I am trying to use recording rule to aggregate metric for improving the query performance, my rule configuration as follow:

```yaml
groups:
- name: qps_rules
  interval: 1m
  rules:
  - record: job:server_latency_milliseconds_count:rate3m
    expr: sum by(server_method,server_url_patterns,app_name) (rate(server_latency_milliseconds_count{env=~"env1|env2|env3"}[3m]))
```

> the above group has above 8 rules,i just skip some other rule to keep simple

From the Prometheus UI, the groups take about 25s seconds each time to evaluate:

[image]

However, the chart of time series shows that there are some data points missing:

[image]

While if I use the back PromQL of recording rule to query, everything works fine:

[image]

I wonder if I miss something when define the recording rule or there is any misconfiguration I should check